# Cloud deployed NArgMin does not obey constraints (but local evaluation does)

Tags: mathematical-optimization, wolfram-cloud

[Edited 20:02 for concision]

*Problem statement:* [NArgMin](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NArgMin.html) correctly obeys constraints when evaluating locally (on `$Version` = "11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)"), but when the cloud deployed version of the function does not correctly obey the constraints and returns different results.

*Minimal broken example:*

```
test2[input_String] := Module[
  {x = ToExpression[input],
   m = {{0.75`, 0, 0}, {0.38`, 5.84`, 0}, {1, 1, 1}},
   v1, v2, v3},
  NArgMin[
    Norm[m.{v1, v2, v3} - Append[x, 1] ],
    Element[{v1, v2, v3}, Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}]],
    AccuracyGoal -> 0.0001,
    PrecisionGoal -> 0.0001]
   // ToString
  ]

example = "{0.0919614, 0.0926934}"
test2[example] (*correctly returns "{0.122615, 0.00789377, 0.869491}"*)
```

In contrast, when deployed to cloud, a different result is returned which violates the positivity constrain on the arguments.

```
api = APIFunction[{"input" -> String}, test2[#input] &]
deployedFunction2 = CloudDeploy[ api, Permissions -> "Public"]

URLExecute[deployedFunction2, {"input" -> example}] (*incorrectly returns "{0.405362, -0.00654954, 0.593471}", which violates the region constraint in NArgMin*)
```

*Conclusion:* I'm puzzled why the cloud version of the NArgMin call returns the wrong result, and does not correctly obey the provided constraints, whereas the local version works OK.  What am I missing here?

Comment: (I reduced this down to an even smaller example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic issue is that you're misinterpreting the meaning of the [`AccuracyGoal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AccuracyGoal) and [`PrecisionGoal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PrecisionGoal). For example:

```
WolframLanguageData["AccuracyGoal", "PlaintextUsage"]
```

> "AccuracyGoal is an option for various numerical operations which specifies 
>   how many effective digits of accuracy should be sought in the final result."

So, using `AccuracyGoal->.0001` means that you'll accept an answer with basically 0 digits of accuracy, or in other words, basically any answer is fine.

As for the difference between M11.3 and the cloud, the cloud uses M12, and there's been a change in behavior for this edge case.

Comment: Aha!  `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal` set number of digits, not values.  Confirmed that this works correctly.  Thanks for your help.